# Is there any way to force at least one column NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, trigger, null

I have a `schedule_days` table that is having `id, day, date` columns.

> **id** - auto increment, primary key
>   **day** - weekday - enum(weekdays) default not null
>   **date** - a specific date - default not null

The schedule is for the train time table. That will have the same routine for all weeks except for any specific date, such as any festival. Thus I have set both null as I want to set either `day` or `date`.

If the date is specified, then I can get the day from it, so it doesn't make sense to ask or force the user to set day, which may cause human error.

I may use **TRIGGER** but would like to know if there is any better way to do in **MySQL - 8.0.*** version

## Table Query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schedule_days
(
    id   INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    day  ENUM ('SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY') DEFAULT NULL,
    date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX staff_index (day),
    CONSTRAINT day_day_check CHECK (`day` IS NULL + `date` IS NULL = 1) # check constraint
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use version 8.0.16 or above, use [CHECK constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html).

Something like

```
CHECK COALESCE(`day`, `date`) IS NOT NULL
```

for "at least one is not null", or

```
CHECK `day` IS NULL + `date` IS NULL = 1
```

for "strongly one is not null".

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [@Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/256151/191738) I am able to resolve the issue. Hee is the final query.

I have created `CONSTRAINT` using `CHECK` (as [@Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/256151/191738) suggested) for `day` and `date` either table `IS NOT NULL`

```
CONSTRAINT day_date_check CHECK ((day IS NOT NULL) OR (date IS NOT NULL))
```

## Table Query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schedule_days
(
    id   INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    day  ENUM ('SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY') DEFAULT NULL,
    date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX schedule_day (day),
    CONSTRAINT day_date_check CHECK ((day IS NOT NULL) OR (date IS NOT NULL))
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```